# Converting serialized form's data to json object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I have a cshtml like the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Plans", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "floorplan-form" }))
{
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FloorPlan.Name, new { placeholder = "Enter text", @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FloorPlan.GroupId, new SelectList(Model.FloorPlanGroups, "Id", "Name"))             
}
```

In my javascript(in a separate javascript file), I'm trying to serialize this form and convert it into a JSON object.

```
var formData = $("#floorplan-form").serialize();
console.info(formData);
```

prints out

```
FloorPlan.Name=Test&FloorPlan.GroupId=15
```

And

```
var formData = $("#floorplan-form").serializeArray();
console.info(formData);
```

gives me:

[image: Screen capture]

I have tried doing this

```
var formData = JSON.parse($("#floorplan-form").serializeArray());
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Change your statement

```
var formData = JSON.parse($("#floorplan-form").serializeArray());
```

with

```
var formData = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#frm').serializeArray()); // store json string
```

or

```
var formData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jQuery('#frm').serializeArray())) // store json object
```

Comment: Does one need to add a reference to an external file? is that `JSON` class included in jQuery ?

Comment: Lol kids these days with their fancy jQuery... the `JSON` object is part of Javascript's [built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). Has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: To modify the formData of jquery file upload, I can only make it via third method, thanks

Answer (score 24):

Use the code below!!!

```
    var data = $("form").serialize().split("&");
    console.log(data);
    var obj={};
    for(var key in data)
    {
        console.log(data[key]);
        obj[data[key].split("=")[0]] = data[key].split("=")[1];
    }

    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you have a serialized string and want to convert it back to an object. It would be helpful to have a little more explanation rather than a code only answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
function jQFormSerializeArrToJson(formSerializeArr){
 var jsonObj = {};
 jQuery.map( formSerializeArr, function( n, i ) {
     jsonObj[n.name] = n.value;
 });

 return jsonObj;
}
```

Use this function. This will work only with jquery.

```
var serializedArr = $("#floorplan-form").serializeArray();

var properJsonObj = jQFormSerializeArrToJson(serializedArr);
```

Comment: You can also use `jQuery.each` in place of `jQuery.map`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for make a json with all fields of form.

**Jquery example:**

```
$('form').serializeArray().reduce(function(accumulator,currentValue, currentIndex){
    if(currentIndex === 1){
        var json = {};
        json[accumulator.name] = accumulator.value;
        return json;
    }
    accumulator[currentValue.name] = currentValue.value;
    return accumulator;
});
```

Pure JavaScript with FormData:

```
var formdata = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
var getJsonFromFormData = (formData) => {
    var json = {};    
    for (item of formData.keys()){
        json[item] = formData.get(item);
    }
     return json;
}
var json = getJsdonFromFormData(formdata);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use: **jquery.serializeToJSON** - https://github.com/raphaelm22/jquery.serializeToJSON
Its is prepared to work with forms ASP MVC

Answer (score 2):

A modern interpretation. babel stage-2 preset is required to compile the object spread operator

```js
// serializeToJSON :: String -> JSON
const serializeToJSON = str => 
  str.split('&')
    .map(x => x.split('='))
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: isNaN(value) ? value : Number(value)
    }), {})

console.log(
  serializeToJSON('foo=1&bar=2&baz=three')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following to convert a serialize data to json object, this would take the array of fields in form and iterate over it asigning the keys and values to a new object.

```
let uncleandata = $(this).serializeArray();
let data = {};
uncleandata.forEach(item=>{
  data[item.name] = item.value;
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: The best answer